# Converting PDF to text format

Tags: density-function

I am searching for a tool/software which can convert PDF to text format for text mining. The PDF files I use, contains many tables.

I tried using PDF Miner, but I found many problems while converting tables in PDF to text.

Can someone recommend a tool that efficiently works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). It does a good job of extracting text from a pdf document.